# Запятая после многоточия, заменяющего только одну-с букву

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, многоточие

Можете сказать, как правильно это задание оформить? Я думаю, 1-й вар. – это правильный вариант, т. к. многоточие просто одну букву заменяет. Более того, целостность нарушается, если те две запятые не ставить-таки.

1. Напишите эти слова (слово *буква* тоже надо написать): *м...рия, тр...нд, **эсс..., камикадз...,** с...ндвич, буква ж..., про...ктор, ду...лянт, ало..., ма...стро, ри...лтор.*
2. Напишите эти слова (слово *буква* тоже надо написать): *м...рия, тр...нд, **эсс... камикадз...** с...ндвич, буква ж..., про...ктор, ду...лянт, ало..., ма...стро, ри...лтор.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много способов оформления пропуска буквы (или букв):
м...рия, тр...нд, эсс..., камикадз... (три точки);
м··рия, тр··нд, эсс··, камикадз·· (две точки, обычно "пожирнее", иногда — посередине);
м_рия, тр_нд, эсс_, камикадз_ (с черточкой внизу);
м.?.рия, тр.?.нд, эсс.?., камикадз.?. (с вопросительным знаком);
с кружочком, с квадратиком, со скобками...

Верен, конечно же, первый вариант: после трех точек (это ведь не знак "многоточие") ставится запятая. А вот в самом конце (при встрече трех точек и заключительной точки) лучше написать с пробелом, чтобы не было четырех точек подряд: **камикадз... .**

Пример (упражнение 22):

> Нет дубовых рощ.., старин..ый нож.., громкий  плач.., не плач.., ноч..ной сторож.. ...

[Е. Андреева. Русский язык на отлично!](https://books.google.ee/books?id=x4Q7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=c3Vw0GSIsz&sig=ACfU3U2PNcb0Po0cPt4Meyua8q3WzlVsBA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy0ue5wYCCAxWwHBAIHeYWCvI4HhDoAXoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B&f=false)

Comment: Там вообще только две точки. А может, не надо ставить в конце помле последнего многоточия вообще никакой точки?

Comment: Знак окончания предложения обязательно нужен. С камикадзе — точка, с ночным сторожем — многоточие, потому что это незаконченная цитата и двух точечек в конце предложения быть не может.

Comment: Почему там-с вооще две, а не три точки?!

Comment: Безобразие какое-то-с!