# Почему столько много учебников используют две точки, чтобы обозначить пропуск, вместо многоточия?

Tags: орфография

Почему столько много учебников используют две точки, чтобы обозначить пропуск, вместо многоточия? Об этом же официально нигде не сказано.

> *Непр..менно* вместо *непр...менно*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, действительно, **как** обозначать пропуск буквы или букв, в правилах не указано.
Но в них четко и официально определено, **где** используется ***пунктуационный знак*** "многоточие" (или троеточие).

> **1. Многоточие** ставится для обозначения незаконченности высказывания, вызванной различными причинами (волнением говорящего, внешними помехами и т. д.)...
> **2. Многоточие** ставится для указания на перерывы в речи, на заминки...
> **3. Многоточие** в конце предложения ставится для указания на то, что приводимое перечисление неполное и могло бы быть продолжено...
> **4. Многоточие** ставится для указания на неожиданный переход от одной мысли к другой...
> **5. Многоточие** в начале текста указывает, что продолжается прерванное какой-либо вставкой повествование или что между событиями, описываемыми в предшествующем тексте и в данном, прошло много времени...
> **6. Многоточие** ставится при перечислении слов с нераскрытым содержанием...

Для "внутренностей" слова ни одна из рекомендаций правил не подходит — то, что находится (или не находится) внутри слова, никоим образом к пунктуации не относится.

Выбор двух точек — это не безобразие, а дело типографики. Главное —  написанное должно быть разборчивым, четким, а также визуально привлекательным для читателя.

Так какой же **символ** "изобразить"?
Хотите — две точки (удобно — с многоточием не спутаешь), хотите — три.
Можно [квадратик](https://saharina.ru/dicts/test.php?name=dict174.xml) поставить, можно [чёрточку](https://grammarian.ru/teaching/5solo/17.html).

[Многоточие](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=90#pp90) (Д. Э. Розенталь. Пунктуация)
[Запятая после многоточия, заменяющего только одну-с букву](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475119/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%83/475844#475844)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отличить пропуск букв от пропуска слов.